# function defined in helper not found in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-helpers

I'm using a helper function to validate XML in Codeigniter.

My helper function is defined in `xml_validation_helper.php` and is as follows:

```
/**
 * Function to generate a short html snippet indicating success
 * or failure of XML loading
 * @param type $xmlFile
 */  
function validate_xml($xmlFile){
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->validateOnParse = true;
    $dom->load($xmlFile);
    if (!$dom->validate())
    {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';
        foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error)
        {
            $result.="<li>".$error->message."</li>";
        }
        libxml_clear_errors();
        $result.="</ul></div>";
    }
    else 
    {
        $result = "<div class='alert alert-success'>XML Valid against DTD</div>";
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I'm using it in my controller (specifically in the `index` method) and that is as follows:

```
 function index() {
    $this->data['pagebody'] = "show_trends";
    $this->load->helper("xml_validation");
    $this->data['pokedex'] = display_file(DATA_FOLDER ."/xml/pokedex.xml");
    $pokedexResult = validate_xml($this->data['pokedex']);
    $this->data['gameSales'] = display_file(DATA_FOLDER . "/xml/sales.xml");
    $gameSalesResult = validate_xml($this->data['gameSales']);
    $this->render();
}
```

However, I keep getting a "`Fatal error: Call to undefined function validate_xml() in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\controllers\show_trends.php on line 15` error, even though I can clearly load the file. I've even tried to move the function into the same file as the `index` method, but it still says it's undefined.

Why am I getting this error, even though this function is clearly defined?

Answer (score 2):

Provided your helper is named the_helper_name_helper.php (it must end with _helper.php) and is located in the `application/helpers` you have to load the helper file using:

```
$this->load->helper('the_helper_name')
```

If you plan on using functions in this helper often, you better autoload it by adding `'the_helper_name'` to the `$config['helpers']` array in `application/config/autoload.php`

Answer (score 1):

```
You must load libraries and helper files in contructor function
check it out
<?PHP
class controllername extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{

    $this->load->helper("xml_validation");
}

public function index() {
    $this->data['pagebody'] = "show_trends";
   // $this->load->helper("xml_validation");
    $this->data['pokedex'] = display_file(DATA_FOLDER ."/xml/pokedex.xml");
    $pokedexResult = validate_xml($this->data['pokedex']);
    $this->data['gameSales'] = display_file(DATA_FOLDER . "/xml/sales.xml");
    $gameSalesResult = validate_xml($this->data['gameSales']);
    $this->render();
}
}

?>
```